# How to delete specific messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm coding a discord bot with node.js.
I want to delete all message starting with "Something" when I call a function.
So I tried to use `fetchMessages` to get all message from a channel and then delete them with a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fetchedMessage.length; i++) {
  if(fetchedMessage[i]...) {
    fetchedMessage[i].delete();
  }
}
```

I have started with:

```
var allMessage = channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 10 });
console.log("All Message = ");
console.log(allMessage);
```

But I can't figure out what to do next :/
Fetched message are some odd object I don't know how to manipulate :(
Does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[`TextChannel.fetchMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages) returns a Promise, so to use the collected items you'll have to use a `.then()` statement. If you need more informations about Promises look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
Try something like this:

```
channel.fetchMessages({limit: 10}).then(collected => { //collected is a Collection
  collected.forEach(msg => {
    if (msg.content.startsWith("Something")) msg.delete();
  });
});
```

You may also need these: [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Collection), [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message).